# What's the origin of the expression "Them's the breaks"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, them-is

What's the origin of the expression "Them's the breaks", meaning "that's how the cookie crumbles"?

Comment: Maybe generalized from the expression ["Them's the rules"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=them%27s+the+breaks%2C+them%27s+the+rules&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), which seems to have been around decades earlier.

Comment: @PeterShor http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that%27s+or+them%27s+the+breaks___1

Comment: There is http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/42/messages/839.html but I don't believe we should be repeating unbounded conjecture as an answer, so I won't.

Comment: @Kris: I was talking about the "them's the" part. From Google Ngrams, it appears that both "that's the breaks" and "them's the rules" have been around for much longer than "them's the breaks".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is of American origin and comes from the game of pool.

Comment: If it's from pool, why is "breaks" plural? It's always singular in pool.

Comment: Does this come from an authoritative source?

Comment: Google Books shows *Them's the breaks* emerging from *That's the breaks [of the game]* (1929-present) in a 1958 story by Robert Sheckley in *Galaxy*. *Breaks of the game* goes back at least to *Billiards: Game, 500 Up* (1846), where the game described appears to my ignorance to be what is now called 'English Billiards'.